# need advice on re-associating an array value with original key

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a program that will grab a bunch of images from a webpage and figure out which of the images is the largest.

So far I've taken the images, put them into an array, used the getimagesize() function to determine the heights.  I then placed all of the heights into another array and sorted them in reverse order to get the largest one.  So far so good.

My problem now is that I must find a way to re-associate the largest image with its initial image link.  I've thought of potentially running the initial code to fetch the images again from the web page.  Then comparing the 1st value in the array I've used to determine the biggest image with the images a second time, but this seems like a waste of bandwidth and I get a feeling there is an easier way to re-associate the height value with its initial image.  Am I right?

```
<?php

$url = 'http://lockerz.com/s/104049300';

// Fetch page
$string = FetchPage($url);

// Regex that extracts the images (full tag)
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$img_tag_array = $out[0];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($img_tag_array); echo "</pre>";

// Regex for SRC Value
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$images_url_array = $out[1];
$image_heights_array = array();

foreach ($images_url_array as $imagelink)
{
if (substr($imagelink,0,7)=="http://")
    {
     $getheight = getimagesize($imagelink);
     array_push($image_heights_array,"$getheight[1]");
    }
}

rsort($image_heights_array);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($image_heights_array); echo "</pre>";
// Fetch Page Function

function FetchPage($path)
{
$file = fopen($path, "r");

if (!$file)
{
exit("The was a connection error!");
} 

$data = '';

while (!feof($file))
{
// Extract the data from the file / url

$data .= fgets($file, 1024);
}
return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your sentence is far too long. Please use full stops and capital letters.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal please learn to read quicker and hold your breath for longer :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off:

```
// Regex that extracts the images (full tag)
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$img_tag_array = $out[0];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($img_tag_array); echo "</pre>";

// Regex for SRC Value
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

HTML parsing regex ewww. Let's simplify this... with an HTML parser.

```
<?php
// EDIT: Use a custom function to do the
// reverse of SORT_NUMERIC with asort
function height_compare($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$url = 'http://lockerz.com/s/104049300';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Okay this is HTML is kind of screwy
// So we're going to supress errors
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

// Get all images
$images_list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

$images = array();
foreach($images_list as $image) {
  // Get the src attribute
  $image_source = $image->getAttribute('src');
  $image_size_info = getimagesize($image_source);

  $images[$image_source] = $image_size_info[1];
}

// Do a numeric sort on the height
uasort($images, "height_compare");
print_r($images);
?>
```

Much shorter and more readable. The result:

```
$ php test.php 

Array
(
    [http://c0013784.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_633aa94] => 328
    [http://ad.doubleclick.net/ad/buz.plixi/photos;pos=300a;celeb=;kw=;tile=2;sz=300x250,300x600;ord=123456789?] => 250
    [http://static.lockerz.com/pegasus/images/video_thumb.jpg?1.0.0] => 207
    [http://static.lockerz.com/pegasus/images/plixi-banner.png?1.0.0] => 107
    [http://ad.doubleclick.net/ad/buz.plixi/photos;pos=728a;celeb=;kw=;tile=1;sz=728x90;ord=123456789?] => 90
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_636f30c] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_637676e] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_63735a0] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_636e73c] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_63795d0] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_636a2c7] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_636bf79] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_636ca08] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_636e419] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_636deca] => 79
    [http://c0013787.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_6384277] => 79
```

Comment: @edmund See the updated code. I used a custom compare function that reverses the order so the tallest image is first, versus the original which used that nasty `array_reverse` at the end.

Comment: fantastic! my only issue though is im having trouble figuring out how to get the value of the first image position in the array, I generally would just echo $array[0] but this method seems to not give this value?

Comment: @edmund You can use `array_slice` like so: `$tallest_image = array_slice($images, 0,1);`

Comment: beautiful! alright so one final question, a bit of a silly one Im sure, but how do I then extract the url out of the array value after using the slice function?

Comment: @edmund you can get that by `key($tallest_image)`

Comment: Im still fairly new to php so this is a bit advanced compared to how i normally would write me code lol

Comment: @edmund As I mentioned though, before going to regex, make sure there's not a function specifically meant to do what you're trying to achieve. This especially goes for HTML, which is meant to represent structure, which is very difficult for regex to cope with, since it's simply trying to match text against a pattern. Not only that, but HTML can use single or double quotes, upper or lower case,  etc. Trying to match every case can get a little weird.

Comment: YES! got it to work! thank you so much for your help, you are truly a programming genius!

Comment: @edmund You can always pop open a separate question if you're trying to figure out what code does, though I recommend looking at the manual for whatever function it is, so you don't ask a question that's already covered by it, getting back a flurry of documentation quote URLs back.

Comment: @edmund also I'm not a genius, I just parse HTML/XML a lot :)

Comment: actually one small problem, and this was actually the reason I decided to put in the if (substr($imagelink,0,7)=="http://") line, when I ran an image search from some sites I would get errors because not all the images returned would include the http:// tag at the beginning which gave errors, so if I use a link such as http://twitpic.com/4wb5ks which contains alot of these this script returns errors, Im thinking I can probably do the same here, but Im not sure where the best place is to insert an if statement specifying only to return image links with the http:// at the beginning

Comment: ive figured it out, i inserted the: if (substr($imagelink,0,7)=="http://") line, after the: $image_source = $image->getAttribute('src'); line, and it works fine for all sites now! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Keep sizes and URLs in one array and use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort multidimensional array.

```
$images_url_array = $out[1];
$images = array();

foreach ($images_url_array as $imagelink)
{
    if (substr($imagelink, 0, 7)=="http://")
    {
        $getheight = getimagesize($imagelink);
        $images[] = array('height' => $getheight[1], 'url' => $imagelink);
    }
}

usort($images, function ($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a['height'] > $b['height']) return 1;
        elseif ($a['height'] < $b['height']) return -1;
        else return 0;
    });
```

Comment: good idea! i do need to ask another question however, is there an array_push() style function that automatically builds an multidimensional array?

Comment: I'm still not a total expert with php so I have to ask what should I try to echo out from the the usort function so I can get an idea of what value it returns?

Comment: @edmund well, try use `print_r($images);` to see. I can't test code, because I haven't list of urls and sizes. Result should be in `$images[0]['url'];`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP so I can't help you with the code, but maybe you could try this idea. Have the first array store an ImageObject. This class to have three properties, imagesize, id, and src.

You can go through the first array, find the imagesize and then sort it by biggest size. Use the id to get individual objects.

Answer (score 0):

if you use [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) the array keys will be preserved, then you can [reset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) the array pointer to start of the array, and get the first [key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php).

But you will also need to preserve the same keys across the images_url_array and image_height_array

```
foreach ($images_url_array as $key => $imagelink)
{
    if (substr($imagelink,0,7)=="http://")
    {
        $getheight = getimagesize($imagelink);
        $image_heights_array[$key] = $getheight[1];
    }
}

//...

rsort($image_heights_array);
reset($image_heights_array);
$largest_image_key = key($image_heights_array);
$largest_image_url = $images_url_array[$key];
```